# Spring STOMP over Websocket - "private" messaging

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I'm working on WebSocket chat. I've made simple one that sends every message to everyone. But I'm trying to make something like private messaging and I really don't know how to do that. I've tried different options but I'don't understand how to make it work.

Here's my code:

*WebSocketConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic/", "/queue/", "/user/");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

*GreetingController.java*

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(Message message) throws Exception {
        return new Greeting(message.getFrom_user_id(), message.getMessage(), message.getTo_user_id());

    }
}
```

And my js function to connect and sending message:

```
function connect() {
var socket = new SockJS('/gs-guide-websocket');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
var theUserId = 1;
stompClient.connect({user:theUserId}, function (frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    //stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
});
}


function sendName() {
stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify(
        {
            'from_user_id': parseInt($("#from_user_id").val()), 
            'message': $("#message").val(),
            'to_user_id': parseInt($("#to_user_id").val())
        }));
}
```

How to make private message work? Could somebody explain me how it should work?

Cheers Andrew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of  **SimpMessagingTemplate** to send the message to appropriate destination queues

Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/SimpMessagingTemplate.html :

```
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    public void greeting(Message message) throws Exception {

     this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/"+message.getFrom_user_id(),message);

    }
```

Accordingly define the subscription to the topics in the client side

Comment: Thank You! Works like a charm :)